# Unable to add new version in itunes

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I'm trying to add new version in itunes.

When I go to,

"My Apps" -> (click on my app) -> "+ Version or Platform" -> then 2 options show: *iOS and tvOS*. I click on iOS (my app is an iOS app) then it is showing popup written as agreement update which has continue button. I click on continue button after that nothing happens.

I have tried clicking the iOS > Agreement update option multiple times on multiple browsers but nothing is happening.

[image]

Comment: click to continue button and accept the new TNC of iTune.

Comment: I click on continue button but nothing is happening or showing.  So how do I accept the TNC of iTunes?

Comment: It might be better to deal with the agreement update on the main iTunes Connect page (before you select My Apps).